# EAGLE GERBER files nit opening in CAM 350

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication

I have chinese factory that I need to assemble PCB.  They cannot open eagle gerber files, only altium how to fix

Comment: We do not know how you export your files, or anything else. Add more description, otherwise it is nearly impossible to answer. With an old ProtomatS62 I have had that I have to export gerber files in "Legacy" mode. But I doubt that it will help you.

Comment: This worked! Can you answer so I can accept.

Comment: Just to be clear exporting via legacy is what worked

Answer (score 0):

They collect source files. Gerber and Excellon files are enough for PCB production, if factory asks for "source code" without sound explanation it is wise to change the factory.